# detached entity issue when updating entity spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've looked at a bunch of answers to similar questions and I haven't found one that solves the issue for me. I feel completely lost right now.

I'm developping a Spring Boot web app, using Spring Data JPA for persistence. I get the following error when I try to do an update to an existing entity:

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.project.timefit.model.WeeklyRoutinePlan

I'm trying to edit an entity WeeklyRoutinePlan using a crudRepository (the get, create and delete methods work fine).

Here is the method in my service

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void editRoutinePlan(WeeklyRoutinePlan routinePlan, String username) {
    WeeklyRoutinePlan oldRoutinePlan = weeklyRoutinePlanRepository.findById(routinePlan.getId()).get();
    oldRoutinePlan.setWeekDay(routinePlan.getWeekDay());
    weeklyRoutinePlanRepository.save(oldRoutinePlan);
}
```

I've simplified it for the sake of debugging, normally i would do a username verification and map the other fields too. I still get the error with this simplified version. And I even get it if I don't change the weekday.

My entity itself looks like this

```
@Entity
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WeeklyRoutinePlan{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Routine routine;
    private LocalTime startTime;
    private LocalTime endTime;
    private Integer weekDay;
    @ManyToOne
    private Program program;

    public void setRoutine(Routine routine) {
        if(routine == this.routine){
            return;
        }
        if(this.routine != null){
            this.routine.getWeeklyRoutinePlans().remove(this);
        }
        if(!routine.getWeeklyRoutinePlans().contains(this)){
            routine.getWeeklyRoutinePlans().add(this);
        }
        this.routine = routine;
    }

    public void setProgram(Program program) {
        if(program == this.program){
            return;
        }
        if(this.program != null){
            this.program.getWeeklyRoutines().remove(this);
        }
        if(!program.getWeeklyRoutines().contains(this)){
            program.getWeeklyRoutines().add(this);
        }
        this.program = program;
    }
}
```

And here are the related entities (although I'm not sure that's relevant since I'm not even updating the relations)

Routine

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Routine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    private String name;
    private Integer numberOfCycles;
    private Color color;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "routines")
    private List<Exercise> exercises;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routine", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<WeeklyRoutinePlan> weeklyRoutinePlans = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routine", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<FrequencyRoutinePlan> frequencyRoutinePlans = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "routine", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<IndividualRoutinePlan> individualRoutinePlans = new ArrayList<>();

    public void remove(){
        exercises.forEach(exercise -> exercise.getRoutines().remove(this));
        exercises = new ArrayList();
    }
    public void setExercises(List<Exercise> exercises){
        exercises.forEach(e -> {
            if(e.getRoutines().stream().noneMatch(r -> Objects.equals(r.getId(), this.getId())))
                e.getRoutines().add(this);
        });
        this.exercises = exercises;
    }

    public void setWeeklyRoutinePlans(List<WeeklyRoutinePlan> weeklyRoutinePlans) {
        if(weeklyRoutinePlans == this.weeklyRoutinePlans){
            return;
        }
        this.weeklyRoutinePlans.forEach(r -> {if(!weeklyRoutinePlans.contains(r))r.setRoutine(null);});
        weeklyRoutinePlans.forEach(r -> {if(weeklyRoutinePlans.contains(r))r.setRoutine(this);});
        this.weeklyRoutinePlans = weeklyRoutinePlans;
    }

    public void setFrequencyRoutinePlans(List<FrequencyRoutinePlan> frequencyRoutinePlans) {
        if(frequencyRoutinePlans == this.frequencyRoutinePlans){
            return;
        }
        this.frequencyRoutinePlans.forEach(r -> {if(!frequencyRoutinePlans.contains(r))r.setRoutine(null);});
        frequencyRoutinePlans.forEach(r -> {if(frequencyRoutinePlans.contains(r))r.setRoutine(this);});
        this.frequencyRoutinePlans = frequencyRoutinePlans;
    }

    public void setIndividualRoutinePlans(List<IndividualRoutinePlan> individualRoutinePlans) {
        if(individualRoutinePlans == this.individualRoutinePlans){
            return;
        }
        this.individualRoutinePlans.forEach(r -> {if(!individualRoutinePlans.contains(r))r.setRoutine(null);});
        individualRoutinePlans.forEach(r -> {if(individualRoutinePlans.contains(r))r.setRoutine(this);});
        this.individualRoutinePlans = individualRoutinePlans;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Routine{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", user=" + user.getUsername() +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", numberOfCycles=" + numberOfCycles +
                ", color=" + color +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Program

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Program {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private ProgramSetting programSetting = ProgramSetting.WEEKLY;
    private Integer frequency = 1;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<WeeklyRoutinePlan> weeklyRoutines = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<FrequencyRoutinePlan> frequencyRoutines = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<IndividualRoutinePlan> individualRoutines = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public void setWeeklyRoutines(List<WeeklyRoutinePlan> weeklyRoutines) {
        if(weeklyRoutines == this.weeklyRoutines){
            return;
        }
        this.weeklyRoutines.forEach(r -> {if(!weeklyRoutines.contains(r))r.setProgram(null);});
        weeklyRoutines.forEach(r -> {if(weeklyRoutines.contains(r))r.setProgram(this);});
        this.weeklyRoutines = weeklyRoutines;
    }

    public void setFrequencyRoutines(List<FrequencyRoutinePlan> frequencyRoutines) {
        if(frequencyRoutines == this.frequencyRoutines){
            return;
        }
        this.frequencyRoutines.forEach(r -> {if(!frequencyRoutines.contains(r))r.setProgram(null);});
        frequencyRoutines.forEach(r -> {if(frequencyRoutines.contains(r))r.setProgram(this);});
        this.frequencyRoutines = frequencyRoutines;
    }

    public void setIndividualRoutines(List<IndividualRoutinePlan> individualRoutines) {
        if(individualRoutines == this.individualRoutines){
            return;
        }
        this.individualRoutines.forEach(r -> {if(!individualRoutines.contains(r))r.setProgram(null);});
        individualRoutines.forEach(r -> {if(individualRoutines.contains(r))r.setProgram(this);});
        this.individualRoutines = individualRoutines;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Program{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", programSetting=" + programSetting +
                ", frequency=" + frequency +
                ", user=" + user.getUsername() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I'm a little desperate at this point because my other entities work fine and I just don't get what I'm doing wrong. The method is transactional so the entity shouldn't be detached when I do the save.

I get the same issue if I don't explicitly call save since that's done by the framework anyway.

I've tried setting the fetch on the relations to LAZY, I've also tried EAGER, I've tried having the cascade on Program be only REMOVE, even though best practice is ALL but I'd read some people had issues with PERSIST.

I've made sure my setters update the relations properly even though as I said I've simplified the update so that I'm not even using them.

I'm at a loss

Comment: I  also refactored to eleminate inheritence for the different RoutinePlan types to eliminate that as a source of problems

Comment: Is the edited `WeeklyRoutinPlan` connected to a `Routine` which have more than the edited one in they `weeklyRoutines`?

Comment: It is connected to a Routine and a Program, since RoutinePlan is essentially a join table with extra planning information between Routine and Program. In my test data there is only one WeeklyRoutinePlan but there could be many that the Routine is connected to.

Comment: You pass an instance `WeeklyRoutinePlan` (routinePlan) to the method. I guess that this is detached, since is it loaded somewhere else. Could you try to pass the id directly as Long (`routinePlan.getId()`). Alternatively try to merge the `routinePlan` and assign the merged entity to `routinePlan` again.

Comment: I tried passing just the id instead of the WeeklyRoutinePlan and saving the oldRoutinePlan after getting it without changing anything. I got the same error. I also tried passing the DTO as parameter instead of the entity and I get the same thing

Comment: To clarify the WeeklyRoutinePlan passed as parameter is a new one with that has been created from a DTO received from a put request i'm sending using Postman

Comment: Ok, i just retested passing the DTO instead of the entity and it seems like my code hadn't recompiled between runs the first and it now works. So the issue is that the entity i'd created from the DTO had an ID and so it was counting as a detached entity even though i wasnt trying to save that one. Thanks a million for helping me find the problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

You pass an instance `WeeklyRoutinePlan` (routinePlan) to the method. I guess that this is detached, since is it loaded somewhere else. Could you try to pass the id directly as Long (`routinePlan.getId()`). Alternatively try to merge the `routinePlan` and assign the merged entity to `routinePlan` again.

-> So the issue is that the entity i'd created from the DTO had an ID and so it was counting as a detached entity even though i wasnt trying to save that one.